# Can not connect to home group vmware virtual computer

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I am using Windows 7, 32x inside VMWare 10.0 virtual machine.

I want to connect to homegroup and type homegroup's password - after that, I receive some error about networking, but nothing specific -> I simply can not connect to home group, which should be the routine operation. My network adapter is set to NAT. What is wrong here?

Comment: You need to specify the errors you receive, even if you think they are "nothing specific."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set the network adapter to bridged, otherwise you are trying to share the same IP address between computers rather than the virtual machine acting like another hosts on the same network.

Comment: See [FAQ](http://vmfaq.com/entry/34/) for details on the difference between VMWare adapter types.

Comment: Setting adapter to bridged has immediately solved the problem.